# How to send custom messages between routers of same network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bash-scripting, openwrt, c

I have created a mesh network with 3 routers in which I have to exchange some small i.e less than 5 character message between the routers.
All of my routers are running on openwrt so it's a Linux system. 
Is it possible with bash script or using any C libraries?

Comment: Have you looked at `nc` or `netcat`?

Comment: you can probably do something with netcat, but that feels like it would be a bit of a kludge. a program of some kind would be a more reliable bet, but it takes time to learn.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll give a try.. Now I'm trying to do that with MQTT..

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible with bash script or using any C libraries?

Well, yes, in standard libc, you'll find the full set of "BSD socket" functions: socket(), bind(), listen(), connect(), and so on. Create a TCP or UDP socket (depending on your needs) and send your data.

It's how all programs make network connections in the first place.

---

Bash on its own can make TCP connections (using redirections to virtual /dev/tcp/* paths), but not accept them, nor work with UDP. External tools such as netcat (nc) or socat – or of course your own C program – are used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not advised the frequency, but it is pretty easy to use ssh and public keys to allow systems to scp files between systems. This does have a lot of overhead, but may be viable if the data only needs to be transferred occassionally and very easy to script.  (netcat as advised by others is lightweight but less secure and not as trivial to implement)